# Find/Search in all currently open pdf documents with a PDF reader?

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader

Both Acrobat Reader and Foxit Reader offer only two alternatives for search/find:

- find only in current document
- find in all documents in a given folder

But I cannot find a search/find option for search/find in **all currently open pdf documents**.

Is there some hiden/undocumented option either in the GUI or from the command line?

Is there any other reader with the option for search/find in all open documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no such option.

Not in AcrobatReader neither in FoxitReader.